# How to run Capybara against a Rails server?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I have a test that uses OAuth2 gem to make make an HTTP request:

```
token = client.auth_code.get_token( code, redirect_uri:redirect_uri )
```

Capybara does not seem to be running the Rails app as a server:

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed:
   Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 3000
```

Here is the config:

```
Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"
Capybara.run_server = true
Capybara.server_port = 3000
Capybara.register_driver :rack_test do |app|
  Capybara::RackTest::Driver.new app,
    follow_redirects:false
end
```

Various docs seem to suggest that the above config will run the app as a server, but it does not seem to be the case.

How to run Capybara against a server so that the server responds to HTTP requests?

EDIT: After digging in the Capybara code, it seems that different drivers have different servers. Working with Poltergeist. So perhaps Poltergeist doesn't support running a server.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not a big expert on capybara, but if I had to guess, I'd say that appserver probably shouldn't have the port in it, if you're also specifying the port elsewhere... otherwise it'll think you're going to `http://localhost:3000:3000` (note: could be totally wrong) :)

Comment: The other possibility is that this Faraday thing is a call to a third party service and it should be stubbed out while testing?

Comment: @TarynEast - I tried it without the port in the `app_host`. Same symptom. The Faraday thing is a class used to make the HTTP connection: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday

Answer (score 0):

As usual, a small detail was overlooked.

The spec must be tagged as `:js`. Otherwise it uses Rack::Test and the server is not started.