# How to monkeypatch a model in Rails test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Use case: When testing an Oauth 2 provider, OAuth2::Client makes an HTTP call from the spec.

The only way I have gotten this to work, is to start a 2nd instance of the Oauth 2 provider using `RAILS_ENV=test rails s`.

Webmock won't work because I want to test the Oauth 2 provider using OAuth2::Client to make the HTTP request, and `Capybara.run_server = true` doesn't work because it doesn't respond to the HTTP request.

I would like to create a mock for a model, similar to an RSpec mock. However, when starting the 2nd instance, it does not load the RSpec mocks (or RSpec, for that matter).

So, the solution I found is to monkeypatch the model after it is loaded in the 2nd instance. I tried changing `config/environments/test.rb`, but I didn't find a way to load the mock after the model is loaded.

So, what is a good way to load a given file in the test environment, after all the Rails models are loaded?

Rails 4.1.6

Comment: I'm unclear why Capybaras server thread wouldn't respond to a request? Sounds like the target url isn't being set correctly

Comment: It has never responded or started for me. I assumed that it does not create a bona fide server, but maybe it is due to the test setup.

Comment: BTW I believe you asked three questions: _How to monkey patch Rails' managed constants_, _Why `Capybara.run_server = true` does not respond to oauth client requests_ and since you weren't set on a solution _How to write integration tests for multiple processes_. I tried to answer first and last.

Comment: @PooyanKhosravi - I was focussed on the first question. I found one good way is to use `Capybara.run_server = true` and RSpec mocks. Figured out why it wasn't working and posted the answer in another SO question.

Comment: @TomWalpole - The test setup was not correct. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747081/how-to-run-capybara-against-a-rails-server.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Railtie](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html). Specifically [Railtie::Configuration#after_initialize](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie/Configuration.html#method-i-after_initialize) if eager loading is enabled or [Railtie::Configuration#to_prepare](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie/Configuration.html#method-i-to_prepare) if Models are reloaded on each request.

```
class MyRailtie < Rails::Railtie
  # Executed after Rails is loaded. If Models are
  # eager loaded every model is defined here
  config.to_prepare do
    # Do monkey patching here.
    MyModel # Make sure Model is required
    class MyModel
    end
  end
end
```

#### Summary

I'm going to drop my 2 cents, hope you don't mind.

1. You are limiting yourself to unit test boundaries while you are writing an integration test.
2. Try to test what you expect from the system not how you expect it to do the grunt work.

#### Unnecessary limitation

There is no need to try to avoid hitting different systems in an integration test.

Expecting a request to be made with a specific method and data is required in a unit test because no other parts of a system should be contacted

In an integration test you just don't have this limitation. There is no need for mocks or monkey patches. You are testing the system as it would run in production. Using mocks in an integration test actually decreases test suite quality.

#### Test actual expectation

I suspect that you don't care what OAuth::Client does. You probably don't care what OAuth server returns. If you are using OAuth and Doorkeeper they are well tested and there is no need to test them again.

What you probably care about is to be able to access a protected resource with whatever token you got from OAuth Provider. Let's test that.

Even if you are trying to test Doorkeeper itself, you don't have to care what a model does you can test models in isolation, test actual data returned from server or how you expect it to respond to following requests.

Comment: "There is no need to try to avoid hitting different systems" - What do you mean by system? If you mean another app, then I don't want to talk to that app. I want to mock it.

Comment: I do want to write a few feature specs (acceptance tests) for OAuth and Doorkeeper so that I know it does the basics and so I know exactly what it does.

Comment: Having said all that, your answer appears to be exactly what I was looking for. The mock would be defined in another file, so can I require it in the `config.to_prepare` block?

Comment: @BSeven no you can't require anything inside `to_prepare`. Require makes sure even if it gets called multiple times actual code is exactly evaluated once. You can define a method in a file that dynamically monkeypatches model via `instance_eval` and call that method in `to_prepare`.

Comment: About _system_, let me explain. A unit test should test a narrow specific scope preferably a class. You can test everything in that scope i.e. subclasses. In integration test what you are testing (a class) and scope (a feature) are two different things. By system I meant scope of an integration test which usually is smallest coherent integrated set of features. In your case that would be OAuth provider and resource server. Basically in integration you can test scope at question (a class) and any other scope that includes your scope. (Opposit of unit)